# Calculating number of inpatient days

Tags: sql

I need to know how to calculate the number of inpatient days for the following:
 If I have a patient that was admitted in October and still is in the hospital in November but I just want to know how to calculate the number of inpatient days in November how do I do this?

Another example if a patient is in the hospital in November and still in the hospital in December and I just want the days in November how do I calculate this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What does your data look like? What are your tables like? What RBMS are you using (sql-server, oracle etc etc)?

Comment: Please provide the code which you have tried for us to help you better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query :

```
declare @sd datetime =dateadd(dd,-5,getdate())
declare @ed datetime = getdate()
select @sd
select @ed

-- Following returns of day diffrence between to dates
select DATEDIFF(DD,@sd,@ed)
```